# Problem loading a tooltip on an html page

Tags: html, css

I'm new with CSS, I'm trying to display an image with some text below when you hover over certain position on the page. The problem is, for some reason the image is not displaying, this is my code:

```css
.foto-jb {
 visibility: hidden;
}

.jb :hover .foto-jb {
 visibility: visible;
 opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="member1">
 <i class="name-person"></i>
 <span class="jb">Name Person</span>
</div>

<div class="foto-jb">
 <img src="./images/photo.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Your path is `./images/photo.png`. Do you have a file called `photo.png` in a folder called `images` that is at the same level as your HTML file?

Comment: No, I just changed the file name to post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of code:

```
.jb :hover .foto-jb {
      visibility: visible;
      opacity: 1;
    }
```

means, once `.jb` class is hovered look for `.foto-jb` class that is inside `.jb` class and make it **visible**.

So what you have to do actually is the following:

```
.member1:hover+.foto-jb
{
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

which means, once `.member` class is hovered look for `.foto-jb` class that is placed immediately after `.member` class and make it **visible**.

You may want to take a look at [CSS Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) it's really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Space is descendant selector and `.jb :hover .foto-jb` selects elements with `.foto-jb` class that are descendants of `.jb` class. Such elements don't exist in your case.

Move your `<div class="foto-jb">` inside `<div class="member1">`, then use a combination of sibling (+) and descendant selector(space) to select the image, or only + to select the `<div class="foto-jb">`.

HTML:

```
<div class="member1">
  <i class="name-person"></i>
  <span class="jb">Name Person</span>
  <div class="foto-jb">
    <img src="./images/photo.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.jb:hover + .foto-jb {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

`.jb:hover + .foto-jb` selects the element that immediately follows the elements with `.jb` class (+ is the adjacent sibling selector).

Comment: Thx for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Need to fix both HTML and CSS

```css
.foto-jb {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.jb:hover + .foto-jb {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="member1">
  <i class="name-person"></i>
  <span class="jb">Name Person</span>
  <div class="foto-jb">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x150/000/fff">
  </div>
</div>
```